# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, jboss, gruntjs, angular7

I have a folder LearningBoard and all my AngularJS content(index.html, js, css files) are inside that folder. I am using grunt.js to generate war file and deploy it on jboss server.

After generating war file all my content is outside web-inf folder. 
I am able to load http://localhost:38080/learningboard but I do not see any content loading. 
In my index.html I have entry like `<base href="/">`.

On console I see

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) styles.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded
>   with a status of 404 (Not Found)

If I put all my content inside web-inf folder then I get 404 resource not found. 
How to load js and css content when I hit http://localhost:38080/learningboard ?

I am using **Angular 7**.

Grunt JS code

```
module.exports = function ( grunt ) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-war' );

    var taskConfig = {
        war: {
            target: {
                options: {
                    war_verbose: true,
                    war_dist_folder: 'warFile',           // Folder path seperator added at runtime. 
                    war_name: 'Test',            // .war will be appended if omitted 
                    webxml_welcome: 'index.html',
                    webxml_display_name: 'Test'
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'dist/learningboard',
                        src: ['**'],
                        dest: ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };

    grunt.initConfig( taskConfig );
};
```

Comment: is 'learningboard', context root of the jboss ?

Comment: Yes learningboard is the context root.

Comment: Could you share your minimal war file ?

Comment: @sangram Did you ever manage to get this figured out? I am having a very similar problem right now. I am just getting a blank page.